# Rounded wireframe with big cells

Tags: nurbs-surface

I'm pretty new to Blender and I'm trying to create a perfectly round NURBS sphere. I need a wireframe of this sphere with big cells (like on the image below) but I also need curved (sic!) not straight edges of cells. Is there a way to do so?

[image: NURBS]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, add a *UV Sphere* to your scene. Now go into edit mode, make sure you are in Face select mode (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and select Face) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Make the resulting edges as large as desired. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection and then press <kbd>Delete</kbd> *> Faces*.

[image: Making the Mesh]

Now go into edit mode and select all by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, and then <kbd>W</kbd> *> Subdivide Smooth* and change the subdivisions up or down as desired.

[image: Subdividing the Mesh]

Now add a *Solidify* Modifier to your object to add some depth. You may also want to add a *Bevel* modifier while you are at it.

[image: Solidify Modifier]

You should now have a nice smooth wireframe:

[image: Final Result]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. For the first steps we need the "face select mode".

Comment: Well there is a problem: with more subdivisions the edges still straight as they were without subdivisions. At least the horizontal ones.

Comment: You need to set the *Smoothness* value in the `T` menu to 1, or use *Subdivide Smooth* as I explained.

Comment: I've tried 1 (default), 2 and some other values. It looks better if I use more segments creating the UV sphere but with more segments the cells are narrower.

Comment: You went into edit mode, selected all faces, and pressed `W` *> Subdivide Smooth*? It has to be a bug. Did you add an entirely new mesh?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm almost happy now with an UV Sphere (30 segments, 15 circles) subdivided with Subdivide Smooth, so I'll try to find out if this is a bug of Blender 2.73 later. Thanks!

Comment: I did use Blender 2.72, so there might be a difference. Glad to help!